# Server Login Failed: Classic ASP App with Service Account - only when windows auth is turned on

Tags: iis, active-directory, asp-classic

I have configured an ASP Classic application with an application pool running under a service account, which has access to the database I'm connecting to.

The connection string includes a `Trusted_Connection=yes` setting.

When I run the application with Windows authentication enabled, I get the error:

> Login failed for user 'NT Authority\Anonymous Logon'

When I run the application with Windows authentication turned off, and anonymous authentication turned on, it will connect to the SQL Server successfully using the service account.

How can I make it so that even during Windows authentication, the service account will be used for login to the database?

Comment: You should be able to add `NT Authority\Anonymous Logon` as a Windows Account in SQL Server and limit its access via a database role.

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows authentication to connect sql server then set your application pool identity to server administrator.

1. Open iis and go to Application Pools.
2. Select your web site, click "Advanced Settings" in the "Actions" panel.
3. Under "Process Model" select "Identity."
4. In the popup, select the "Custom account" radio button.
5. Set the account and password to your server administrator.

Comment: Do not make the server administrator the application pool identity, this is a massive security risk.

Comment: Besides this answer doesn't really answer the question of the question, adding the server administrator is a quite bad idea, as already mentioned. It should be a service account with only the rights needed.